# 'end' expected near '<eof>' in Lua

Tags: lua

I have tried to realize adding numbers in lua:

```
local Calculator = {};
function Calculator.get( frame )
 local new_args = str._getParameters( frame.args, { 'f', 'o', 's' } );
 local f = tonumber( new_args['f'] ) or 1;
 local o = ( new_args['o'] ) or ""; 
 local s = tonumber( new_args['s'] ) or 1;
 Calculator.ret(first, second, operation);
end

function Calculator.ret (f, o, s)
 if(o == "+") then return f+s;
end

return Calculator
```

Even if place a end in end, error doesn't disappear.

Comment: Also drop the semicolons. They're unnecessary and not really idiomatic.

Comment: your function call `Calculator.ret(first, second, operation)` is also wrong. `first`, `second` and `operation` are `nil`. your variables are `f`, `o` and `s`. And the order of parameters is also wrong. You should call `Calculator.ret(f, o, s)`. Also using () in the if-statement is not necessary. Further you don't use the return value of your Calculator.ret call, so your Program doesn't actually do much

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz This is convention, FYI. I also use semicolons and empty statements

Comment: @Hand1Cloud Yes, it's a convention, and it's specifically Lua convention to not use the semicolons. They're a remnant of the dark past only created for compilers, and there's no reason to perpetuate this unnecessary syntax noise. And empty statements are a corner case which doesn't apply here.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Empty statements don't appear in his code, but are supported at least on Lua 5.2. Don't get me wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function Calculator.ret (f, o, s)
 if(o == "+") then return f+s end
end                            ^----------------- here
```

`if` in Lua *always* has to have an `end` (kinda unlike `{}` for `if`s in C-like languages).

Comment: `{}` is a block statement in C..., not at all, though.

Comment: Feel my -1 :)))

Comment: The asker prefers to explicity terminate certain statements for convention.

Comment: @Hand1Cloud I said nothing about semicolons in this answer, so I don't know why would you downvote it. Please explain.

Comment: Sure, see your `if` line. Check its last character, `'d'` > `44 00`, instead I expected to see a `;` yet, like in the question. Any problem keeping it?

Comment: Why did u remove it?

Comment: @Hand1Cloud Yes, it's against the common style and I prefer it that way. I am not obliged to mimick the OP's style.

Comment: Anyways you'll let people confused if they're not familiar to any programming language. :v... So, won't say anything about it?

Comment: @Hand1cloud excuse me? If someone doesn't know any language, he can't prefer either style.

Comment: They don't know what a `;` is? Keep it or explain

Comment: @Hand1Cloud not in context of programming, no. What would be more confusing for someone learning Lua would be code that unnecessary uses semicolons. All recommended Lua tutorials have code without them, so it would just cause more confusion, like you're doing right now. Anyway, you're free to keep your pointless downvote over your disagreement with the most common and recommended Lua style, this is not the place to discuss this further.

Comment: Fine. And if you want my downvote to disappear, you'd rather edit the post, is not it? Because I can't undo it 'til edit.